# Unknown DecisionId [type=ACTIVITY, id=26], AWS SWF Decision error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have been facing this issue intermittently, once in 2 weeks. As I observed, each time this issue occurs, all are due to activity Id 26. I see activity id 26 got completed successfully. Not sure why decision task is failing with the activity which got completed successfully.

> "eventTimestamp": 1500668941.164,
>  
>   "eventType": "`WorkflowExecutionFailed`",
>   "eventId": 866, "workflowExecutionFailedEventAttributes": 
>   "details": 
>   "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: `Unknown DecisionId` [type=ACTIVITY, id=26]. 
> The possible causes are `non-deterministic workflow definition` code or `incompatible change` in the workflow definition.
>
> at: com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionsHelper.getDecision(DecisionsHelper.java:613)
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionsHelper.handleActivityTaskScheduled(DecisionsHelper.java:171)
>  
>   at:
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider.processEvent(AsyncDecider.java:267)
>    com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecider.decide(AsyncDecider.java:515)
>   at:
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.AsyncDecisionTaskHandler.handleDecisionTask(AsyncDecisionTaskHandler.java:50)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.DecisionTaskPoller.pollAndProcessSingleTask(DecisionTaskPoller.java:201)
>   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericWorker$PollServiceTask.run(GenericWorker.java:94)
>
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)",
>
> "decisionTaskCompletedEventId": 865,
>   "reason": "`Unknown DecisionId` [type=ACTIVITY, id=26]. 
>   The possible causes are `non-deterministic workflow definition` code or incompatible change in the workflow definition."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Flow Framework uses replay to reconstruct the workflow state. It requires that workflow code is deterministic. I.e. it gets exactly into the same state when a history is replayed. There are multiple ways to break determinism. The most common is workflow code (or configuration) change while some workflows are running or using system time instead of Clock object provided by the framework. 
Do you do any time calculations or have you changed your workflow code recently?

See [Making Changes to Decider Code: Versioning and Feature Flags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/java-flow-making-changes-decider-code.html) for various ways of updating workflow code without breaking running workflows.

Comment: We don't have any time calculations. Workflow code changes every time we add new feature. But, there were no code changes on the day of issue.

Comment: Change doesn't need to be in the day of issue. If you deploy a change when there are open workflows without taking special measures the replay will be broken at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What are special measures needs to be taken care?

Comment: Added link to Making Changes to Decider Code doc